# Colab: How to run a specific codeblock

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run a specific code in colab with different input arguments, and record the results

Let's say, for simplicity, my colab notebook looks like this. 
[image]

As an alternative to manually changing the arguments every time(obviously there are much more arguments than the example given)

Is there a way to do the 'run codeblock 3' in google colab?

Answer (score 0):

Why not put your arguments in to either a list or dictionary, since it looks like you're manually entering them anyway.

For a list you could do:

```
   args.input = [5, 10, 15, 20]
```

then

```
saved = {}
for i in args.input:
  sum = 0
  for j in range(i):
    sum += j
  saved[str(i)] = sum
```

Which saves your results in a dictionary:

```
>> saved
{'10': 45, '15': 105, '20': 190, '5': 10}
```